# Time based process killing VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

what I'm trying to do is to code an app for killing a process within a desired time(minutes). Main goal is check if the process is running , if it is running; ask to kill process, if not; still wait in the background and check if it is running. Im not a coder myself, just downloaded and tried to code a simple app. So excuse me for my bad coding skills.

Heres my code, I have 1 timer, 1 status bar and 1 button. Also heard that timers only handle 1 minute but I dont know how to convert it's interval to minutes.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Timer1.Interval = 1800
        CheckIfRunning()

    End Sub
    Dim p() As Process
    Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
        p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Zoom") 'Process name
        If p.Count > 0 Then
            ' Process is running
            ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "ZOOM IS RUNNING"
        Else
            ' Process is not running
            ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "ZOOM IS NOT RUNNING"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim ZOOM() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Zoom")
        Dim ask As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("30Min limit, Kill Zoom?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            For Each Process As Process In ZOOM
                Process.Kill()
                Timer1.Stop()
                Timer1.Interval = 1800
                Timer1.Start()
            Next
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer1.Interval = 1800
            Timer1.Start()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's sort of working but, when the 30 minute limit is complete, it spams the same messagebox. And I couldn't get it to work properly, so could use some help.

Comment: `Timer1.Interval = 1800` sets the Timer interval to `1.8` seconds. You're calling `CheckIfRunning()` only on Form.Load, so nobody know whether the Process is terminated after that point. You should do that in the Tick handler, where you also check whether the 30 seconds period has timed-out: you may want to compare DateTime objects to verify that, setting the timestamp when the Timer is started -- Don't show a MessageBox in/from an event handler that's called by a timer without pausing the Timer first. -- There's no need to store `p()`

Answer (score 1):

The `Interval` value for a timer is the number of milliseconds, not seconds. So `1800` is `1.8` seconds, not `30` minutes.

Since in your `Timer1_Tick` you're almost immediately calling `MsgBox` and you say that you are getting message boxes spammed at you, I think you're probably using the wrong kind of timer. Make sure you're using the Windows Forms timer for a Windows Forms app.

It's also a good idea to call `Timer1.Stop()` before showing any UI to prevent spamming anyway.